# Android market api session login

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

i got exception  `Caused by: com.gc.android.market.api.LoginException: The login request used a username or password that is not recognized.`

```
MarketSession market = new MarketSession();
market.login(email,pwd);

        market.getContext().setAndroidId(AndroidId);
        String query = "maps";
        AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder().setQuery(query)
                .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10).setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                .build();
        market.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
                // Your code here
                // response.getApp(0).getCreator() ...
                // see AppsResponse class definition for more infos
                String crString = response.getApp(0).getCreator();
                Log.i("tag", crString);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like Google deprecated login and password auhtorization in 2012.

See "[ClientLogin for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps)"